# How do I make this Firebase login system work?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase-authentication

I am working on a weather forecast app with React (I am usin React Router) in the frontend and Node in the backend. I decided that I wanted to implement a login system using Firebase to try it out. Now I'm stuck because I can make the user register and login (in the /register and /login path) but when I go to the Home page (the / page) it says the user is null or something along the lines of

Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.

But I am using console.logs to see if the user is being loaded and it is, I can see the JSON data with the token in the console.

For example, when I try to load the user.email, when the React app reloads by itself when the file is saved, the email shows up, but when I reload the page with the ctrl+r it says user is null.

I think it may have something to do with the onAuthStateChanged, useEffect or a missing/wrong async await.

Here is the code (at least the parts which I think are causing this problem):

AuthContext.tsx

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect, ReactNode } from 'react'
import { onAuthStateChanged, User } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '../firebase-config'

interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<any>(null)

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User | null>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, currentUser => {
      if (currentUser) {
        setUser(currentUser)
      } else {
        setUser(null)
      }
    })

    return () => unsubscribe() 
  }, [])

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user }}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Home.tsx

```
import { useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import ForecastCard from '../components/ForecastCard'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import { WeatherData } from '../types/weatherTypes'
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext'

function Home() {
  const location = useLocation()
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
  const cityName = queryParams.get('cityName') || 'Washington'
  const [weatherData, setWeatherData] = useState<WeatherData | null>(null)
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWeatherData = async () => {
      try {
        if (user) {
          const token = await user.getIdToken()
          const response = await fetch(
            `http://localhost:5000/api/weather/${cityName}`,
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              },
            }
          )
          const data: WeatherData = await response.json()
          setWeatherData(data)
        } else {
          console.log('User not logged in')
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error:', error)
      }
    }
    if (user) {
      fetchWeatherData()
    }
  }, [cityName, user])

  return ( Home html and style... )
}

export default Home
```

Login.tsx

```
import React, { useState, useContext, ChangeEvent, FormEvent } from 'react'
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'
import { auth } from '../firebase-config'
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext'

const Login: React.FC = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(AuthContext)
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [error, setError] = useState('')

  const handleEmailChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value)
  }

  const handlePasswordChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value)
  }

  const handleLogin = async (e: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    try {
      if (!email || !password) {
        setError('Please provide email and password.')
        return
      }

      const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        auth,
        email,
        password
      )
      const currentUser = userCredential.user
      setError('')
      console.log(currentUser) // Log the user object after successful login
    } catch (err: any) {
      setError(err.message)
    }
  }

  return ( Login html and style...  )
}

export default Login
```

First of all, I tried using some console.logs to see if the user was being loaded. It was, but it appears that it doesn't really work when I reload the page with ctrl+r.

I tried using chatgpt, but it says the code should work, which is not.